# Apache 2 - RewriteRule - inject index.php in secure context

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

On our server, the security team disabled DirectoryIndex, so I have to figure how to add index.php in the vhost

it works, but the problem is that in sub folders, the page resources refer to the root domain name instead of that subfolder (so I get 404's)

so the very RewriteRule that add the index.php, seems to mess the resource loading and it does not make any sens to me

```
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^/subfolder$"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/subfolder$ /subfolder/index.php
```

how can I solve this ?

thanks

Comment: anyone ????????

Comment: hi admin, can you remove this...thanks